# React hooks array specific problem with structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have specific array with questions from database.
I don't know how many of questions are in array so I created structure with functions map on element

```
<Fragment>
  <div className="paddingSection">
    <h1 className="large text-primary">Form Questions</h1>
    <form className="form" onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
      {form.questions.map((el, index) => (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>{el}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={form.questions[index]}
              name={index}
              required
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            />
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      ))}
      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-1" />
    </form>
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

Now I need to get answers for the questions and send it to database in array element. But i don't know how to do that correctly.
I wrote that:

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');
const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
const onChange = (e) => {
  //taken from actuall input
  setAnswer(e.target.value, answer);
  //table of all elements
  setFormData([answer, ...formData]);
};
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addResponseToForm(match.params.company, match.params.id, formData, history);
};
```

But i'm getting something like that:

`7: "write"
8: "writ"
9: "wri"
10: "wr"
11: "w"`

I understand that I get real time response but how to take the final answer for the simple question?

Comment: `setAnswer(e.target.value, answer)` is wrong, the `setAnswer` function only takes a string value for the `answer`.

Comment: Other than that, it's unclear what you're trying to do and where it fails. Please include a [mcve] and a clear description of what's the expected behaviour.

Comment: what would/should happen if a user types on only the 1st 3rd and 5th input elements ? What would you want submitted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non of this answers was working but i changed some parts and is working perfectly.

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
 const onChange = (e) => {
   setAnswer({ ...answer, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   setFormData([answer, ...formData]);
 };

 const onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   let arr = Object.values(formData[0]);
   addResponseToForm(match.params.company, match.params.id, arr, history);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`setAnswer()` should take one argument, either the new value or a function. I see you're passing 2 params.

```
//taken from actuall input
setAnswer(e.target.value, answer);
```

In this case, `answer` is actually the previous value of this state variable. 
An easy fix for your scenario might be to just replace `setAnswer(e.target.value, answer);` with `setAnswer(e.target.value);`.

On a separate note, here's a few things that might clear up later confusions:

- Using both `answer` and `formData` seems redundant.
- `onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}` can be replaced with `onChange={onChange}`. the event gets passed along automagically.
- Using `index` as `key` will result in repeat keys and unnecessary re-renders.

Let me know if you need any further assistance. I'm happy to help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as a quick fix (*although more info on what you want to accomplish might garner better suggestions*)

- `onChange` and `onSubmit` can be passed directly to the form and inputs
- `form.questions[index]` is the same as `el` so use that inside the loop
- the `answer`, `setAnswer` are not usefull in this case since you do not know when the user finished typing
- you can use the `name` (*since it is the index*) of the `input` to target the index of the `formData` array if that is what you want.

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
const onChange = (e) => {
  setFormData((data) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    updatedDate[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    return updatedData;
  });
};
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addResponseToForm(match.params.company, match.params.id, formData, history);
};
```

```html
<Fragment>
  <div className="paddingSection">
    <h1 className="large text-primary">Form Questions</h1>
    <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {form.questions.map((el, index) => (
        <Fragment key={index}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>{el}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={el}
              name={index}
              required
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      ))}
      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-1" />
    </form>
  </div>
</Fragment>
```